# Any way to turn off the reputation (points) gain notification

Tags: support, notifications

(I have been googling for a while however haven't found a relevant Q&A; fine to be removed if duplicate.)

I prefer not to get any notifications when the reputation is gained because of the questions I raised or the answer I gave, however I'd like to keep informed of the reputation loss.

Side question: I'm not interested in `review` or other editing jobs assigned therefore I expect those notifications to be turned off.

Is there any way to customize them?

Comment: No. You cannot customize that.

Comment: Waiting for a Jon Skeet request for this feature! Hitting reputation cap every day must be annoying! We must stop the upvote, we are actually harrasing users!